# Give a class to a div when 2 input files are not empty

Tags: jquery, input

I have done this code. It's suppose to give a class to a div when the both input files are not empty. But it doesn't work.

**JQUERY**

```
if($("#video_imagen, #video_imagen").val().length != 0){ $(".video_upload_success").addClass('active'); }
```

**HTML**

```
<input type="file" id="video_imagen" name="video_imagen" required />
<label id="video_imagen_btn" class="upload_file_button btn" for="video_imagen">IMAGEN</label>

<input type="file" id="video_file" name="video_file" required />
<label id="video_file_btn" class="upload_file_button btn" for="video_file">VIDEO</label>
```

The inputs have a `display: none;` I have styled the labels.

**UPDATED**

This is what happens when both inputs are not empty
[LINK](https://i.gyazo.com/8cded205947da8999cdb7bf925b54b8e.png)

It should be like this when the files loads. When you give the class, that div appears...
[LINK](https://i.gyazo.com/b19a7dae05e49e0a1d23d3349f9b160f.png)

Comment: Where are you adding the add class code? I mean after what event?

Comment: In a div that's afterwards. When it has the class "active", a success picture appears

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with that code... the only reason why may be not working is because a class or id spelling issue... or Jquery not loading

but if you want you can try : http://jsfiddle.net/leojavier/z870pbw6/4/

```
     if($("#video_imagen1").val().length>0 && $("#video_imagen2").val().length>0){ 
        $("p").addClass('active'); 
    }else{
        $("p").removeClass('active'); 
    }

$('a').on('click', function(){
      if($("#video_imagen1").val().length>0 && $("#video_imagen2").val().length>0){ 
        $("p").addClass('active'); 
          //$('form').submit();
    }else{
        $("p").removeClass('active'); 
    }
});
```

I just noticed... you have the same ID twice

Comment: neither. Quite annoying

Comment: check that code :) you need to add an event listener

Comment: just added a version where it will remove the class if you remove all the characters from one textbox :)  I hope this helps man

Comment: check the link I posted in my answer: http://jsfiddle.net/leojavier/z870pbw6/1/... every time you type something it will check both fields and set the class if they both have data... otherwise it will remove the css class

Comment: The problem is that im not typing in the inputs. I'm loading files. They're input files, not input texts

Comment: ooh so you need to check the html() method... let me update the script... one sec... you need to check if there are images in both containers right?

Comment: Yeah, that's right. One image and one video file. 2xInput file not empty

Comment: test removing one of the images or remove the url of one of the images

Comment: Zzz, you dont understand what I need. You have 2 input type file. You click one, and you upload an image, you click the other one, and you upload a video. You have 2 inputs with an IMAGE and a VIDEO. Because of that, a div appears, because of the class you gave it when you upload those two files. Then, you have to click the submit button and upload the files to the database.

Comment: What I just want it's to check if the input files have anything inside to upload. If they have an imagen and a video, then the div appears.

Comment: That's it. Thanks too much buddie